# VBA Excel set Formula [=INDEX(Matrix;Row;Col)] to cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

As the title says: I'm trying to set the Index function to a cell, using VBA. For some reason it does not work.
I don't see why, since the formula works when I write it to the cell manually ("word1" will appear in cell A1).

Here is my approach (not working):

```
Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=INDEX(B5:B8;E1;1)"
```

The rest of my code doesn't matter since applying other formulas work. Working example:

```
Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=SUM(E1:H1)"
```

My excel sheet looks like this:

```
    A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I
1                           1     2     3     4  
2
3
4
5   1   word1
6   2   word2
7   3   word3
8   4   word4
```

Thanks for helping me here!

Comment: How about `"=INDEX(B5:B8,E1,1)"` ?

Comment: *'it does not work'* is not a valid error code nor error description.

Comment: @Jeeped, sorry, you are right, i missed that.

Comment: @newacc2240: right answer!! that solved the problem! so easy, thank you so much :)

Comment: @newacc2240 can you put that as an answer so Max can mark it answered?